# Using Inheritance with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my first Rails application (my first Ruby app, for that matter) and I have a best practice question about inheritance. I have to be able to upload physical media and I want to store the physical properties separately in the database so that certain attributes can be queried outside of the application as easily as within in. To manage this, I have an `images` table and a `binaries` table. The former stores metadata specific to images, of course, while the latter stores physical file metadata that will apply to a range of file types. Once I have my approach solidified, I'll add a `swfs` table, a `videos` table and perhaps others.

At the moment, I have a `BinaryObserver` class captures the `before_create` callback of an image and uploads the physical file - the binary. This is working fine, but I'm wondering about other approaches. Specifically, I'm wondering if I couldn't (and shouldn't) establish a basic inheritance model where `Binary` extends `ActiveRecord::Base` and `Image` extends `Binary`.

As it stands right now, `Image belongs_to Binary` and `Binary has_one Image`. Since there's an obvious `is-a` relationship, though, should I use inheritance? Does rails even support such a thing when interacting with a database? This might be the best way to reduce the amount of work required to support a new file type.

Would appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on this. I'm experimenting with the language and the framework, so I'm trying to learn best practices before I get in too deep.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, there is a very nice single-table inheritance built into rails.

Unfortunately, what you are looking for is multi-table and support is pretty bleak.

Check out some examples on how people have implemented such:

http://zackham.com/2008/8/21/multiple-table-inheritance

http://github.com/sava/class_table_inheritance/tree/master

http://github.com/rwl4/inherits_from/tree/master

Or you could just switch to single-table inheritance (though that defeats your previous comment):

```
class Binary < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Image < Binary
end
```

and add this to your Binary model:

```
type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

Examples:

```
@binaries = Binary.find(:all)

@images = Image.find(:all)
```

Comment: Ah, polymorphic associations. This is pretty nice, actually, and should be all that I need. Nothing I can envision would extend Image; everything would just extend Binary. If I understand the brief additional reading I've done, I'd also have to reverse the polarity of my current relationship. At the moment, my foreign key is on the images table.

The more I think about it, this sounds like a perfectly sound way of meeting my needs, but I'm not sure it's significantly better than what I have in place now. I'll have to play with it and determine how much easier it is to add new subtypes.

Comment: My bad, iano. I misunderstood single table inheritance in Rails and you're right. It doesn't meet my needs. I don't want to jam everything up into one table and denormalize my data that way. I guess I'll stick with my observer, but not for the reason I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

From the DB point of view, you don't need the binaries table. If you save the binary data in the database, it's just a property, like date, and you wouldn't make a dates table.

To say that Image extends Binary because Image "*is-a*" Binary is not accurate, Image "*is-made-of*" binary, like Person made of Flesh (you wouldn't say Person extend Flesh).

Anyway, there is a plugin for attachments: [`attachment_fu`](http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu/tree/master), use it :)

Comment: We may have to agree to disagree :-). First, I want to share the physical file metadata. Images, SWFs, videoes, etc. all have common properties of file size, extension, etc. I don't want to store those in each individual table (and image metadata is different from SWF data, etc.).

Second, I would argue that an image is a specific type of file. Hence, the is-a relationship. Maybe the difference is in how you look at it. In my case, I need to track several types specifically, but lump other types (text, Word Doc and others) into a more generic class.

Comment: Paperclip is also nice for handling attachments.

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing production code and not just testing out stuff, then I highly recommend `attachment_fu` or similar way to handle this situation.